# C++ 2d array. delete or delete[]?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is the copy constructor and destructor in the implementation of a dummy class called Foo.
Constructor

```
Foo::Foo(int n): size(n) 
{

 A = new(nothrow) ArrayType *[size];
 assert(A);

 for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
 A[i] = new (nothrow) ArrayType[size+2];
 assert(A[i]);
 for(int j = 0 ; j < size; ++j)
  A[i][j] = VALUE;
   }
 }
```

Destructor

```
Foo::~Foo()
{


for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    delete[] A[i];
}

delete[] A;

}
```

array declaration in .h file.

```
ArrayType **A;
```

Hello all, my program dynamically allocates a 2d array and then deallocates it at the end of the program. My question is, should i use delete in my destructor or delete[]? which is correct? My program executes fine both ways however i cannot tell if either one causes undefined behavior or a memory leak in the background.

Comment: You could replace `new(nothrow)`...`assert`  with `new`  . An exception will be thrown which has similar effect to an assertion failure if you didn't have a catch handler.

Comment: I'd like to keep the new(nothrow) assertion.

Comment: You must call `delete[]` for each block allocated by `new[]` , so it looks OK as you have it

Comment: Simple: if you `new` an array, then you need `delete[]`.

Comment: thanks, you guys are great.

Comment: @flower [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d18d48a3575d8a0) is one way it'll go south. It allocates 1000 objects, but only one destructor is ever called because of the wrong `delete`.

Comment: But depending on what you are doing consider not using a 2D array at all. They have some significant disadvantages over a 1D array and manually indexing the second dimension with `array[row * number_columns + column]`